# Refactor optional parameters method to remove `if` statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optional-parameters

I have a method `select_active_buildings` with three parameters that default to `nil` to filter my database using provided information.

```
def select_active_buildings(category:nil, upgrader:nil, upgrade_resource:nil)
  my_active_buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  if category && upgrader && upgrade_resource
    return my_active_buildings.where(category:category, upgrader:upgrader, upgrade_resource:upgrade_resource)
  elsif category && upgrader
    return my_active_buildings.where(category:category, upgrader:upgrader)
  elsif category && upgrade_resource
    return my_active_buildings.where(category:category, upgrade_resource:upgrade_resource)
  elsif upgrader && upgrade_resource
    return my_active_buildings.where(upgrader:upgrader, upgrade_resource:upgrade_resource)
  elsif category
    return my_active_buildings.where(category:category)
  elsif upgrader
    return my_active_buildings.where(upgrader:upgrader)
  elsif upgrade_resource
    return my_active_buildings.where(upgrade_resource:upgrade_resource)
  else
    return my_active_buildings
  end
end
```

I need help refactoring this method.

Comment: This question would be better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks, you are both right.

Comment: As mentioned - this should be on Code Review :)

Comment: Yes, I'll post there next time, whoops! Is there a possibility to change it now? Or just leave it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're working with ActiveRecord, Mongoid, or something else with a chainable `where`, you can take advantage of the fact that this:

```
o.where(:a => b, :c => d)
```

is the same as:

```
o.where(:a => b).where(:c => d)
```

That lets you do this:

```
def select_active_buildings(category: nil, upgrader: nil, upgrade_resource: nil)
  buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  buildings = buildings.where(category: category) if(category)
  buildings = buildings.where(upgrader: upgrader) if(upgrader)
  buildings = buildings.where(upgrade_resource: upgrade_resource) if(upgrade_resource)
  buildings
end
```

or even:

```
def select_active_buildings(conditions)
  buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  %i[category upgrader upgrade_resource]
    .select { |f| conditions.has_key?(f) }
    .inject(buildings) { |q, f| q.where(f => conditions[f]) }
end
```

Comment: I went with your first option. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this:

```
def select_active_buildings(category: nil, upgrader: nil, upgrade_resource: nil)
  my_active_buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  cond = {
    category: category,
    upgrader: upgrader,
    upgrade_resource: upgrade_resource
  }.select { |k, v| v }
  my_active_buildings.where(cond)
end
```

Or,

```
def select_active_buildings(category: nil, upgrader: nil, upgrade_resource: nil)
  my_active_buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  cond = {}
  cond[:category] = category if category
  cond[:upgrader] = upgrader if upgrader
  cond[:upgrade_resource] = upgrade_resource if upgrade_resource
  my_active_buildings.where(cond)
end
```

Or, if I don't really care about syntax checking at the `select_active_function` level,

```
def select_active_buildings(cond)
  my_active_buildings = self.buildings.active(self.townhall_level)
  my_active_buildings.where(cond)
end
```

If you really don't want the `.where({})` case, you can put `return my_active_buildings if cond.empty?` before it.

Comment: A variant on the last would be `where(cond.slice(:category, ...))`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def select_active_buildings(category: nil, upgrader: nil, upgrade_resource: nil)
  buildings.active(self.townhall_level).where(
    **({category: category} if category).to_h,
    **({upgrader: upgrader} if upgrader).to_h,
    **({upgrade_resource: upgrade_resource} if upgrade_resource).to_h,
  )
end
```